# Ag-Grid( JS) : Need to show total of each column at the top/bottom in tree grid and the respective value of each node in every node's column in a row

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

[Location Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdcRY.png)

We have a location tree where each location(parent/child) contains some data for that particular node, refer to the screenshot for the same. We need to show the total of the whole tree at the top/bottom. Note: don't want children's data sum in the parent node, parent node needs to show only the parent node's data.

I tried with row pinning which seems a costly operation if i need to sum up all the data for all the columns at frontend and if i need to get the data for total from the backend  when all the data for Aggrid comes up, it will increase the server response time( calculating total is time consuming at backend)

Is there a way to manipulate the data at frontend through pivot or any other functionality.

P.S : i tried with pivot as well with footer. All the data of children sums up on parent node , it doesn't consider parent data.Tried to customise pivot's aggFunc: sum method, there i was able to add parent data and children data at parent node,total in footer came out correct as well

[Customised parent+children data sum at parent node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7oZS.png)

but this didn't solve my problem as i need only respective node's data( not children's summed data) on every node and the total .
[Needs this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikEVZ.png)